# WINUI 3.0 - WeakEventManager missing

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, winui-3, weakeventmanager

I cannot find the WeakEventManger class in WINUI3.

All my WPF projects uses this in the view models when I subscribe on model events that lives longer than the ViewModel.

ViewModels with long living models must be a common thing.

E.g. a short living view model subscribing to the Clipboard.

What is best pratise in WINUI3?

```
public class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _text;
        
    public ItemViewModel()
    {
        // GC collects MainViewModel, but WeakEventManager does not exist in WINUI3
        //WeakEventManager<Clipboard, object>.AddHandler(Clipboard, nameof(Clipboard.ContentChanged), OnClipboardContentChanged);

        // GC does not collect MainViewModel
        Clipboard.ContentChanged += OnClipboardContentChanged;
    }

    private void OnClipboardContentChanged(object sender, object e)
    {
        Text = Clipboard.GetContent().GetTextAsync().AsTask().Result;
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            if (_text != value)
            {
                _text = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Text)));
            }
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I encountered this problem, too, both IWeakEventListener and WeakEventManager are missing in WinUI3 for now

Answer (score 0):

It's marked as hidden from Intellisense for some reason, but it's under the  `CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Helpers` namespace:

https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Windows/blob/main/components/Helpers/src/WeakEventListener.cs